# How to find series of highest peaks of a repeating pattern using find_peaks() in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to determine the highest peaks of the pattern blocks in the following waveform:
[image]

Basically, I need to detect the following peaks only (highlighted):
[image]

If I use `scipy.find_peaks()`, it's unable to detect the appropriate peaks:

```
indices = find_peaks(my_waveform, prominence = 1)[0]
```

It ends up detecting all of the following points, which is not what I am looking for:
[image]

I can't provide the input arguments of `distance` or `height` thresholds to `scipy.find_peaks()` since there are many of the desired peaks on either extremes which are lower in height than the non-desired peaks in the middle.

*Note: I had de-trended the waveform in order to aid this above problem too as you can see in the above snapshot, but it still doesn't give the right results.*

So can anyone help with a correct way to tackle this?

**Here's the code to fully reproduce the dataset I've shown ("autocorr" is the final waveform of interest)**

```
import json
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import pickle

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, acf, pacf
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, square
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#GENERATION OF A FUNCTION WITH DUAL SEASONALITY & NOISE

def white_noise(mu, sigma, num_pts):
    """ Function to generate Gaussian Normal Noise
    Args:
        sigma: std value
        num_pts: no of points
        mu: mean value

    Returns:
        generated Gaussian Normal Noise
    """
    
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, num_pts)
    return noise

def signal_line_plot(input_signal: pd.Series, title: str = "", y_label: str = "Signal"):
    """ Function to plot a time series signal
    Args:
        input_signal: time series signal that you want to plot
        title: title on plot
        y_label: label of the signal being plotted
        
    Returns:
        signal plot
    """
    
    plt.plot(input_signal)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.show()

t_week = np.linspace(1,480, 480)
t_weekend=np.linspace(1,192,192)
T=96 #Time Period
x_weekday = 10*square(2*np.pi*t_week/T, duty=0.7)+10 + white_noise(0, 1,480)
x_weekend = 2*square(2*np.pi*t_weekend/T, duty=0.7)+2 + white_noise(0,1,192)
x_daily_weekly = np.concatenate((x_weekday, x_weekend)) 
x_daily_weekly_long = np.concatenate((x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly))
signal_line_plot(x_daily_weekly_long)
signal_line_plot(x_daily_weekly_long[0:1000])

#x_daily_weekly_long is the final waveform on which I'm carrying out Autocorrelation

#PERFORMING AUTOCORRELATION:
import scipy.signal as signal

autocorr = signal.correlate(x_daily_weekly_long, x_daily_weekly_long, mode = "same")
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(x_daily_weekly_long), len(x_daily_weekly_long), mode = "same")

#VISUALIZATION:
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(40)
f.set_figheight(10)
plt.plot(lags, autocorr)
```

Comment: this looks like optimization, so you need to provide a fully reproducible dataset

Comment: It seems that you need an algorithm that finds the maximum in a slicing window instead of an algorithm that finds peaks.

Comment: cant you just use the found peaks as a new dataset and run another round of find_peaks() on it?

Comment: @mozway I've added in the code to reproduce the dataset. You can run it as-is.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco could you please help out with how it's done? I've added in the code to reproduce the dataset

Comment: @EnigmAI not sure what you did but your code produces an entirely different signal

Comment: @Eumel are you sure you're looking at the correct variable? I've rechecked and it's exactly the same code I've used to produce the signal I've shown. "autocorr" is the final signal of interest.

Comment: @Eumel also, I did try running another round of find_peaks() on the previously identified peaks, but it results in detecting the same set of previous peaks only.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco how do you propose to use a slicing window to deal with this?

Comment: @mozway how do we go about this? I've provided a fully reproducible dataset now.

Comment: @mozway do you know from the beginning what is the periodicity of the function in exam?

Comment: @EnigmAI sorry, too many questions, I forgot ;) [here is my attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71707361/16343464)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have some kind of double (or even triple) signal, I would attempt a double smoothing.

One to remove the overall trend, and one to remove the sharp noise.

A picture is probably better than a long explanation:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def smooth(s, win):
    return pd.Series(s).rolling(window=win, center=True).mean().ffill().bfill()

plt.plot(lags, autocorr, label='data')

WINDOW = 100   # needs to be determined empirically
               # and so are the multipliers below

# double smoothing difference + clipping
ddiff = np.clip(smooth(autocorr, 2*WINDOW)-smooth(autocorr, 10*WINDOW), 0, np.inf)
plt.plot(lags, ddiff, label='smooth+clip')

peaks = find_peaks(ddiff, width=WINDOW)[0]
plt.plot(lags[peaks], autocorr[peaks], marker='o', ls='')
plt.plot(lags[peaks], ddiff[peaks], marker='o', ls='')

plt.legend()
```

output:

[image: peak detection]

##### smoothing the original signal

As often in data analysis, the earlier you perform a transformation might be the better. You could also clean your original signal before running the autocorrelation. Here is a quick example (using the `smooth` function defined above):

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x2 = smooth(x_daily_weekly_long, 100)
autocorr2 = signal.correlate(x2, x2, mode = "same")

plt.plot(lags, autocorr2)
idx = find_peaks(autocorr2)[0]
plt.plot(lags[idx], autocorr2[idx], marker='o', ls='')
```

[image: auto-correlation on smoothed data]

cleaned signal:

[image: signal]

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes i used a rough reconstruction of your signal.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, square
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(3,103,10000)

sin = np.clip(np.sin(0.6*x)-0.5,0,10)
tri = np.concatenate([np.linspace(0,0.3,5000),np.linspace(0.3,0,5000)],axis =0)
sig = np.sin(6*x-1.2)

full = sin+tri+sig
```

peak run #1

```
peaks = find_peaks(full)[0]
plt.plot(full)
plt.scatter(peaks,full[peaks], color='red', s=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

peak run #2 + index reextraction (this needs the actual values from your signal)

```
peaks2 = find_peaks(full[peaks])[0]
index = peaks[peaks2]
plt.plot(full)
plt.scatter(index,full[index], color='red', s=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What I realized is that your approach is working perfectly well if there's no noise - like in the dataset you created. But if you run my code to generate the signal, then you can see that due to the presence of noise in the signal, even the bottommost points are getting highlighted (due to miniscule noise peaks). What can be done to smooth them out, such that your logic becomes robust enough to deal with noisy signals as well? Or is there any other way to deal with this issue?

Comment: @EnigmAI this should be fixable with some of the arguments in `find_peaks` in run #1 i would try prominence and width. Alternatively you can use smoothing akin to what mozway did or with a much shorter window (will keep secondary peaks but smooth out noise).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the period you can do this:

```
w=T
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(40)
f.set_figheight(10)
plt.plot(lags, autocorr)
plt.scatter(lags[signal.find_peaks(signal.convolve(autocorr, np.ones(w)/w, mode="same"))[0]], autocorr[signal.find_peaks(signal.convolve(autocorr, np.ones(w)/w, mode="same"))[0]], color="r")
```

Result:

[image]

I don't know if it works in other cases.

EDIT:
another approach is to find the maximum in a slicing window, but also in this case you must define empirically a window size.

```
w=900
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(40)
f.set_figheight(10)
plt.plot(lags, autocorr)
plt.scatter(lags[filters.maximum_filter(autocorr, size=W)==autocorr], autocorr[filters.maximum_filter(autocorr, size=W)==autocorr], color="r")
```

Result:

[image]